# Basic Popup window not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having a small problem with a popup window I am trying to create.

When a button(anything with a certain ID) is clicked it should open(this seems to work) but then when it is open I want it so if you click on anything but the main popup window it should close.

But it does not seem to close when I click on the .overeverythingCover which has width: 100% and height: 100%;

http://jsfiddle.net/mnW7U/

```
$('#activatePopOver, .overeverythingCover').click(function() {
        popUpOverEverything();
   });
```

---

```
function popUpOverEverything(data) {
    // if exists | remove it
    if ($('.overeverythingCover').length) {
        $('.overeverythingCover').empty();
        $('.overeverythingCover').removeClass();
        $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
        console.log("hehe");
    } else {
        $('body').append('<div class="overeverythingCover"</div>');
        $('.overeverythingCover').append('<div class="overEverything"</div>');
        $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
        $('.overEverything').html(data);
    };
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: Sorry didn't get you properly, so you want to close the popup when someone click inside the popup?

Comment: I would like to close it when someone clicks on anywhere except the popup

Answer (score 2):

You can't use "click" handler to an element which not exist yet. You can use .live :

```
$(function() {
    $('#activatePopOver, .overeverythingCover').live('click', function() {
        popUpOverEverything();
   });

    function popUpOverEverything(data) {
        if ($('.overeverythingCover').length > 0) {
            $('.overeverythingCover').remove();
            $('body').css('overflow', 'scroll');
        } else {
            $('body').append('<div class="overeverythingCover"</div>');
            $('.overeverythingCover').append('<div class="overEverything"</div>');
            $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
            $('.overEverything').html(data);

            // Just close when you click outside the popup
            $('.overEverything').click(function(event){
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        };
    }
});
```

See the Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/mnW7U/3/

Comment: i wouldn't recommend using ```live``` since it was deprecated (and actually removed) quite a while back.

Comment: Totally true, but in the Fiddle, only Jquery 1.6 was loaded, "on" was available since Jquery 1.7.

Comment: oops I didn't actually look at the fiddle

Answer (score 1):

use a delegate event listener such as:

```
$(document).on("click", '#activatePopOver, .overeverythingCover', function() {
    popUpOverEverything();
});
```

Like The Wobbuffet mentioned, the issue is that the `.overerverythingCover` div isn't on the page at the time you're binding your event.

NOTE: This will only work with jQuery 1.7+

for older versions you can use `.delegate()`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that you are binding a click event to an element that not yet exists on the page.

I have updated your fiddle with a simple to understand example: http://jsfiddle.net/mnW7U/2/

I created a `popDown()` function that gets bound with the following function when the button is clicked:

```
 $('.overeverythingCover').click(function() {
      popDown();
 });
```

Comment: Hi, thanks worked perfectly! Any way I can make the popup div take the height of the other elements inside of it instead of just going to 100% when I remove the height attribute.

Comment: The height should automatically adjust based on the divs contents.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this:

```
$('body').append('<div class="overeverythingCover"</div>');
```

It is being appended after the click event is added to it. Try adding it to the dom (none-js in the html) then messing with it's `display` property.